# Tapestry Component object Persist issue

Tags: tapestry

I've created a component I use in a form.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
<noscript class="js-required">
    ${message:javascript_required}
</noscript>
<t:content>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <h2>Vehicle:</h2>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>
                VRM:
            </td>
            <td>
                    <input t:type="TextField" t:value="vehicle.vrm" t:id="vrmTextField" t:validate="minlength=3,maxlength=15" size="30"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</t:content>
```

And the java

public class VehicleComponent {

```
@Property
Vehicle vehicle;

VehicleComponent() {
    vehicle = new Vehicle();
}

public void clear() {
    vehicle = new Vehicle();

}
}
```

The problem is is tha after I submit the form this component is part of, the value in the textfield stays - I want it to be cleared from the field. My other simpler components that use Sting, int etc properties all clear.

componentResources.discardPersistentFieldChanges() doesn't work on the vehicle component, nor does a direct call to the clear method above. I feel like if I was to add @persist to the vehicle Object then the componentResources.discardPersistentFieldChanges() would work - but I cant because you can't instantiate a @persist-ed object. If I remove the @Property then I get a null pointer.

Any advice on how to clear the object values from the fields in my component after a persist? Is my only option to capture the values first using @Persist then build the object on submit if I want to clear the components fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `vehicle = new Vehicle();` in `onSuccessFromForm()`.
Or you can change your `vehicle.vrm` to `vehicle?.vrm` and then set `vehicle = null` in `onSuccessFromForm()`.